# Generating Unique Combinations from a list of possible repeated characters

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am looking to generate combinations from a list of elements. Right now i am using a approach of generating power set. For example to generate combinations from {a,b,c}, i will enumerate 001,010,100 ,101 etc...and take the element for which the corresponding binary index is set to 1. 
But the problem comes when there are repeated characters in the list Say {a,a,b}. the above approach would give a,a,b,ab,ba,aab. where as i would like to see only a,b,ab,aa,aab.

I was thinking of writing some binary mask to eliminate repeated strings but was not succesfull.
Any thoughts on how to generate unique combinations ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generate bit vectors, you can generate vectors of positive integers of length equal to the number of distinct elements, subject to the restriction that each component can range from 0 up to the multiplicity of the corresponding element.  In your example above, there are two distinct elements (a and b) with multilpicities 2 and 1, respectively.  Therefore, you would get

```
a b
-------
0 1 --> b
1 0 --> a
1 1 --> ab
2 0 --> aa
2 1 --> aab
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I am trying to implement. I will first find the unique charter set and enumerate possible binary strings. Then for each binary strings i will calculate possible repeated charcater strings based on no of repeatition.
So my problem is now given a string like ab, with repeat count of a=2 and repeat count b=2, i need to geneate ab,aab,aabb,abb. Any thoughts on how to generate this.

Comment: @james I think that would depend on the details of the programming language you're using and the requirements of the problem.  For instance, do you need to have all these combinations in memory at once?  Do you only need to print them to the screen?  Do they need to be strings in the C sense, or can they be something more abstract?  I would suggest either editing the original question with this additional information or asking a new question if you consider these issues to be sufficiently separate from the original post.